# Descender collides with horizontal line

Tags: tables, typography

I don't know if this is an issue with this particular font, but I'd like to know how to correct colliding descenders (and sometimes ascenders) in tables.
Thank you,
A

[image: Q tail almost touches the horizontal line]

```
\usepackage[norule,flushmargin]{footmisc} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Garamond Premier Pro} \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Ligatures={Common}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
\hline
Q & Quota \\
\hline
p & g \\
\hline
T & l \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

*************************************EDITED with further problems*************
@Bernard

My short example is quite long: but you can see at the end of the first table (no errors) the colliding Q in the second column.

The second table gives errors whatever combinations of Sm or Sl I choose in the longtable definition, WHEN I set the \linewidth for the first column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside, showtrims]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{277mm}{170.9877mm}{*}
\settrims{0mm}{17mm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{18.999mm}{37.997mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{18.999mm}{44.837mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{1.4mm}{18.999mm}{1em}
\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\normalfont\itshape\footnotesize}
\sideparmargin{outer} 



\checkandfixthelayout[nearest] 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\usepackage{longtable,tabularx,ltxtable}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Garamond Premier Pro} \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Ligatures={Common}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}



\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{ | S{l} S{m{\linewidth*4/8}} | }

\hline
\multicolumn {2} {|Sc|}{DELL'VNISONO  } \\
\hline
Se'l Soprano sarà & Vnisono col Tenore,  \\
Et il Basso sarà & Terza sotto il Tenore; \\
l'Alto si porrà & Quinta, o Sesta sopra'l Basso.  \\
\hline
Ma se'l Basso sarà la & Quinta sotto'l Tenore,  \\
L'Alto farà la & Terza, ouer Decima sopra'l Basso.  \\
\hline
Similmente se'l Basso fusse & Sesta sotto'l Tenore,  \\
L'alto potrà esser & Terza, ouer Decima sopra'l Basso.  \\
\hline
Et se'l Basso sarà vna & Ottaua sotto'l Tenore,  \\
L'altre parti si porranno & Terza, 5. 6. 10. 12. sopra il Basso.  \\
\hline 
Essendo poi & Decima sotto'l Tenore  \\
L'alto si farà per vna & Quinta, ouer Duodecima distante dal Basso.  \\
\hline
Ma se'l fusse & Duodecima, allora  \\
L'Alto si potrà porre & Terza, ouero Decima sopra il Basso.  \\
\hline
Così essendo il Basso & Quintadecima sotto'l Tenore,  \\
L'Altre parti si porranno & Terza, 5. 6. 10. 12. 13. sopra'l Basso.  \\
\hline
\multicolumn {2} {|Sc|}{DELLA TERZA  } \\
\hline
Se'l Soprano sarà & Terza col Tenore,  \\
\& il Basso sarà & Terza sotto di lui, \\
L'Alto  si potrà fare & Vnisono, ouero Ottaua con le parti.  \\
\hline
Essendo poi il Basso & Sesta sotto'l Tenore,  \\
l'alto si porrà & Terza, o Decima sopra'l Basso.  \\
\hline
Ma se'l Basso fusse & Ottaua sotto'l Tenore,  \\
Allora l'Alto sarà & Quinta, o Sesta, sopra il Basso.  \\
\hline

\end{longtable}



\begin{longtable}{ | S{l{\linewidth*3/8}} S{m{\linewidth*4/8}} | }

\hline
\multicolumn {2} {|Sc|}{DELL'VNISONO  } \\
\hline
Se'l Soprano sarà & Vnisono col Tenore,  \\
Et il Basso sarà & Terza sotto il Tenore; \\
l'Alto si porrà & Quinta, o Sesta sopra'l Basso.  \\
\hline


\end{longtable}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Q\mbox{}uota works but the ligature "Qu" disappears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In typography, a "strut" is an object with depth and/or height but no width and hence is invisible. By inserting a suitably-sized "bottom strut" in the first row of your table, you can increase the separation between the bottom of the descender and the subsequent `\hline`. Similarly, a "top strut" can be used to increase the distance between an ascender and the preceding `\hline`. It's possible to insert both top and bottom struts on a given line.

The following example shows your original table (without struts) on the left and a version *with struts* on the right. Feel free to adjust the height of the top strut and the depth of the bottom strut (`2.6ex` and `1.3ex`, respectively) to suit the characteristics of the font you use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures   = {Common,TeX}, 
             Numbers     = OldStyle,
             Contextuals = Alternate
            ]{Garamond Premier Pro} 

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.3ex]{0pt}{1.3ex}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TBstrut}{\Tstrut\Bstrut} % top&bottom struts

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
\hline
Q & Quota  \\
\hline
p & g  \\
\hline
T & l  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
\hline
Q & Quota \TBstrut \\ %% top and bottom strut
\hline
p & g \Bstrut \\  %% bottom strut only
\hline
T & l \Tstrut \\  %% top strut only
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cellspace` package, which is done for that – ensure a minimal vertical spacing between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and between the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. All you have to do is to prefix the relevant column specifier with the letter `S`, unless you use `siunitx` and its `S` specifier; in the latter case, siunitx changes the prefix to the letter `C`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures = {Common,TeX},
             Numbers = OldStyle,
             Contextuals = Alternate
            ]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
\hline
Q & Quota \\
\hline
p & g \\
\hline
T & l \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ | Sc | Sc |}
\hline
Q & Quota \\
\hline
p & g \\
\hline
T & l \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. I wasn't aware of the `cellspace` package until I read your posting.

Comment: @Mico: unfortunately, it's not a panacea: it's not working under certain circumstances or when used with certain packages. But in a ‘normal’  context, it's quite useful. The `tabls` package is supposed to do about the same job, but I never was able to make it work: either there are a lot of error messages, or it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Interesting. For what it's worth, I used the strut method described in my answer for about 15 years for all tables in my own working papers -- until just a few years ago, when I became familiar with the `booktabs` package and its great macros. Since then, I studiously avoid `\hline` and `\cline` in my own writing, and I have no regrets. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I agree with you. But even with booktabs (that I've been using for more than 15 years…) it may happen that the spacing looks too tight, and cellspace can be useful if you want avoid typing lots of `\addlinespace`.  On another  hand, some (rare) tables do need vertical rules. Ialso used the strurt mathod from time to time, but I prefer not to have to compute its height by trial and error.

Comment: Bernard&Mico, your answers inspired many improvements on my book. Thank you! A

Comment: @Bernard, does cellspace work with longtables? \begin{longtable}{ | m{\linewidth*3/8} m{\linewidth*4/8} | } usually works, but if I set Sm it gives errors.

Comment: @user56153: it *should* work – it works with p{fixedwidth}.Write it with a pair of braces, in the form: `S{m{\linewidth*3/8}}`. You also can define new columntypes, say A, B, &c., and write in the preamble `\addparagraphcolumntypes{A,B}. The example in the doc does it for the `X` type (from tabularx).

Comment: I can't understand what it is: the only combination that works without errors is \begin{longtable}{ | S{l} S{m{\linewidth*5/8}} | }. Not all the collisions are solved though, on some random lines the Q still touches the bottom hline. Whenever I change l to m or I try to fix the length of the first column it freaks out and says ! Class memoir Error: Illegal pream-token (\linewidth*3/8): `c' used. Memoir doesn't like it?

Comment: I'm sorry: I don't use memoir. Perhaps `cellspace` conflicts some settings of memoir? Could you post a minimal (non) working example? Also, there is an alternate solution with the `makecell` package, but it doesn't in all cases either.

Comment: I'll add it in my post above.