# How to change the default strut parameters?

Tags: spacing, typography

By default, TeX inserts a strut in lines with a height and depth of `0.7\baselineskip` and `0.3\baselineskip` respectively. These are the minimum height and depth of the lines.

My question: Is there any way to modify these default settings for the `\strut` in lines? Let's say that I want to make the minimum height of each line equal to `\f@baselineskp` (the current height of the single line space) and to have a minimum depth of 0. I am not sure if this is good typography; I'm just looking into testing it out.

I've tried to change the default `\strut` height and depth without success. See my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
%Attempt 1: I attempt to redefine \set@fontsize from the latex2e kernel. This fails to compile.
%\def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
%    \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
%    \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
%    \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
%    \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}%
%    \edef\f@linespread{#1}%
%    \let\baselinestretch\f@linespread
%      \def\size@update{%
%        \baselineskip\f@baselineskip\relax
%        \baselineskip\f@linespread\baselineskip
%        \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
%        \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
%          \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
%                \@depth.3\baselineskip
%                \@width\z@}%
%%        \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
%%          \vrule\@height\baselineskip
%%                \@depth.0001\baselineskip
%%                \@width\z@}%
%   \ifnum \tracingfonts>\tw@
%      \ifx\f@linespread\@empty
%        \let\reserved@a\@empty
%      \else
%        \def\reserved@a{\f@linespread x}%
%      \fi
%      \@font@info{Changing size to \f@size/\reserved@a
%                \f@baselineskip}%
%      \aftergroup\type@restoreinfo \fi
%        \let\size@update\relax}%
%}
%
%Attempt 2: Doesn't work for some reason.
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
    \vrule\@height\f@baselineskip
            \@depth\z@\@width\z@
}
%\maxdepth\z@
\makeatletter
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I will leave this question up in case someone finds it helpful. I looked through `source2e.pdf`, particularly `ltpara.dtx`, and figured out the following solution:

Just add a strut at the start of each paragraph to ensure that it has a minimum height. For example, `\AddToHook{para/begin}{\rule{\z@}{\f@baselineskip}}` sets a minimal height equal to the current line height and`\AddToHook{para/begin}{\rule{\z@}{\f@size\p@}}` sets a minimal height equal to the current font size.

Comment: tex does not insert struts by default (and latex does not add them in normal paragraph text), so it is hard to know how to answer this.

Comment: paragraph lines are positioned `\baselineskip` apart. fonts for the latin script typically have the reference point 30% up the font bounding box, but tex does not assume this.

Comment: as no struts are used in `\Blinddocument`  redefining `\strutbox` has no effect. If you showed (perhaps by annotating an image) what output you expected, someone would show how to achieve that. I can not guess, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I need to rework my question. I think of letters of having a "height" equal to the height of the single line space. So, in this sense, the value of `\topskip` would be `\f@baselineskip` and headings would have their own `\strut` equal to `\f@baselineskip`. I'm looking to make something like this the default. If this isn't clear, I may remove this post and try again later with a different and more complete explanation. I was mistaken about my idea of TeX putting struts in paragraph text by default.

Comment: it is not clear to me (and doesn't match tex's model at all) but someone may understand what you mean and answer, so don't close just for me:-)

Comment: Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209988/ of interest?

Comment: are you trying to achieve "grid" typesetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered my question by adding a strut at the beginning of every paragraph via hooks.

This ensures that each line has a minimum height. For example, `\AddToHook{para/begin}{\rule{\z@}{\f@baselineskip}}` sets a minimal height equal to the current line height and `\AddToHook{para/begin}{\rule{\z@}{\f@size\p@}}` sets a minimal height equal to the current font size. If the paragraph touches the top of page, change the value of `\topskip` to ensure that that line has the same minimum height as the other lines.